# How to tell if a reference is released in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to refactor code that uses `let` to declare a module scoped Auth instance which is later reassigned (in the same module) due to a configuration change.  The original implementation looks like this.

```
let client = new Auth({ config });
// ...later in the same module
export const updateConfig = (_config) => { client = new Auth(_config) };
```

My first question, is the original Client released after `updateConfig()`. How would you prove that?
Are there any drawbacks to this approach?

My proposed refactor aims to make this a little less magical, by wrapping the Auth module in a singleton with an implicit constructor. However, it requires a getter for the instance. But, in essence it does the same thing by re-assigning a reference when a new configuration is applied.

```
function Client(options) {

  if (Client._instance) {
    return Client._instance;
  }

  if (!(this instanceof Client)) {
    return new Client(options);
  }

  this._instance = new Auth(options);

}

Client.prototype.getInstance = function() { return this._instance };
Client.prototype.updateConfig = function(opts) { 
  this._instance = new Client(opts).getInstance();
}

// usage
const client = new Client({ foo: 'bar'});
client.updateConfig({bar: 'baz'});
console.log(client.getInstance()); // eg. { bar: 'baz' } works!
```

Same questions apply, from a code safety and memory management perspective, which solution is more appropriate?  These are Authentication classes, so I want to make sure they are collected properly and not potentially abused.

Comment: Your revised function does not do anything with the "options" argument passed to `updateConfig()`; what's the point of even having that API?

Comment: I think it does, no?  It passes new options to a new Client constructor.

Comment: _"I want to make sure they are collected properly and not potentially abused."_  What about someone doing `var mycopy = client.getInstance()` and then using `mycopy` for whatever even after `updateConfig` is called, their copy will still be the original - is that something you want to protect against also?

Comment: I would suggest that in absence of evidence to the contrary, you're best off simply trusting the garbage collector.  You can't control how users of your code will keep references to instances.

Comment: Btw `Client._instance !== client._instance !== Client.prototype._instance` - those are 3 different references

Comment: @JamesThorpe, that's a good point, but I don't have to worry about that as much because there will be no access to this instance outside of the module, so it really just to keep internal developers from abusing.

Comment: No it doesn't.  The first thing the constructor does is check for the `_instance`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My first question, is the original Client released after updateConfig()?

Maybe, if `client` is the only variable that references it.

> How would you prove that?

Make a memory dump in the console and search for those client objects.

> Are there any drawbacks to this approach?

No, as long as no one is referencing the client which you expect to update:

```
 const referenced = client;
 updateConfig();
 console.log(referenced === client); // false
```

> My proposed refactor aims to make this a little less magical ... but, in essence it does the same thing

Why is it "less magical" if you hide that change behind 20 lines of code? If I would be the reviewer, I would reject this change, because it introduces some unexpected behaviour, and provides no benefit whatsoever:

```
 console.log(new Client === new Client); // true, wtf
```

How I would refactor that (good comments are underestimated):

```
 // Note: client gets re-set in updateConfig(), do not reference this!
 let client = new Auth({ config });
```

> From a code safety and memory management perspective, which solution is more appropriate?

"but, in essence it does the same thing ". Wise words.

Answer (score 1):

When we call `new` on a constructor function, it will always return a new object which means that when `client` was mutated later, it now definitely holds the new value. That is one thing.

The other thing is that javascript runtime environment garbage collector and looks for the objects which are in memory but are not reference from any variable and if found remove them.

So basically when I do this

```
let obj = {name: 'Hello'}
```

`obj` referes to some object with `2ABCS` memory address and when I mutate it

```
let obj = {name: 'World'}
```

It now refers to object with address `1ABCS` which makes `2ABCS` orphan which means it will be removed by garbage collector

For more read https://javascript.info/garbage-collection

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, GC is not a big concern for potentially abusing the information available in objects. It is the objects themselves. With modern day developer tools, one can easily get into any part of front end code and make sense out of it unless it is obfuscated. IMO, Obfuscation is pretty much necessary these days. One it reduces the file size and second makes it bit difficult to nerds using the code in production.

Now coming to the actual question. Once a new instance `new Auth` is assigned to `client`, the old instance is no more hard referenced by `client` so it is eligible to garbage collection provided no other references are held. There is no guarantee on how quickly the memory is reclaimed.

And advantage of using `let` is it's scope. It is restricted to its block. However, it is not uncommon to have huge blocks. Compared to global vars, `let` offers you a small scope and hence may get released soon after the block ends. It may also be the case that Javascript runtime may utilize method stack for `let` variables and as soon as block ends (method), it will drop the stack and hence the references are also dropped.

Finally, it is absolutely fine to have the way it is and your implementation does not offer any advantage over the previous one.